# Programmatically hiding a view controller from a tab bar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a tab bar application. Is there a way I can programmatically hide one view controller from the scroll down list and from the "edit" list (but still be able to pop it on screen with a certain action, i.e. by calling its tabbarcontroller index)?

The problem is that I have now so many viewcontrollers that completely fill the "edit" screen. So I want to hide some of them and be able to trigger the hidden ones trough some action performed on one of the visible ones.

Thanks

Comment: What is the "_scroll down list_" and the "_edit list_" ? I don't really understand your problem :/

Comment: Some more details would HELP us ..so we can in turn HELP you. :|

Comment: Thank you guys. When a tab bar application has more than 4 tabs or so, an extra tab appears at the bottom right hand side with the label "More". If you click on it you get a scroll down list from which you can choose the desired tab. On the right hand side of the bar at the top there will be an "Edit" button which if clicked will allow you to rearrange all the tabs. Hope I managed to explain myself clearly!